# Can't access or ping some websites, majority are non-https

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns

As title say, I currently using Windows 10, several days ago i had no problem with browsing these websites but recently suddenly all of em are blocked, i still can access certain website like tomsguide.com for http and google and facebook for https. but i can't access others that i try example when i open gamespot.com or this website it fails with ERR_CONNECTION_ERROR from my chrome.

I already try everything in the list but no result.

- Restarting wireless modem.
- Disable Windows Firewall.
- Troubleshoot network connection.
- Flush DNS
- Resetting network settings.
- Ping websites and get fail result.
- Using other device with same wireless connection get an OK result.
- Updating all adapter to up to date.

here where tracert fails. 
(P.S: i can access all of those from VPN software or Zenmate plugin, i once had same issues but i able to system recovery that on my windows 8. This windows 10 seems deleting all my system recovery so i can't do it anymore.)

[image]

Comment: So these websites work if you are connected to a VPN, that sounds like, a DNS issue then.

Comment: ah, is it same as this then ? OS problems ?
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/345jmo/windows_10_dns_issue/

Comment: I have no idea if it is the same issue, you have not answered my question, so waiting on that before I comment further.  [**You are aware that Level 3 has suffered a massive network failure today, right?**](http://www.neowin.net/news/level3-suffering-major-outages-effects-are-felt-worldwide)

Comment: i not answered ? i already answer in ps tho.. well

yes, i can access all of em with a VPN.

Comment: I was asking for a confirmation, that normally is answered, with either a "yes" or "no".

Comment: I just try it on different devices. have different websites that can accessed and not. Seems it's the article you share is true, thank you very much. i tho my pc got some viruses again haha. sry for trouble.